# JSON Decoder Type Mismatch Error in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

When I try to decode JSON I get the error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1972", intValue: 1972), CodingKeys(stringValue: "song_name", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

1. JSON:

```
[
  {
    "song_id": 1373123,
    "song_name": "신라의 달밤",
    "artist": "현인",
    "album": "현인",
    "Like_count": 100,
    "Lyric": "아~ 신라의 밤이여\n불국사의 종소리 들리어 온다\n지나가는 나그네야 걸음을 멈추어라\n고요한 달빛 어린 금오산 기슭에서\n노래를 불러보자 신라의 밤 노래를\n\n아~ 신라의 밤이여\n아름다운 궁녀들 그리워라\n대궐 뒤에 숲 속에서 사랑을 맺었던가\n님들의 치맛소리 귓속에 들으면서\n노래를 불러보자 신라의 밤 노래를",
    "cover_url": "https://image.bugsm.co.kr/album/images/200/1134/113497.jpg?version=20170925032718.0"
  },
...
```

2. Swift code

```
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            self.songs = try decoder.decode([Song].self, from: asset.data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

3. Model

```
struct Song: Codable {
//    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var artist: String
//    var album: String
//    var like: Int
//    var lylic: String
//    var coverURL: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case id = "song_id"
        case title = "song_name"
        case artist = "artist"
//        case album = "album"
//        case like = "Like_count"
//        case lylic = "Lyric"
//        case coverURL = "cover_url"
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything works with the JSON you posted. The error means that `song_name` was a number instead of string. Perhaps, in the real JSON there is sometimes an object with `song_name` being a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is crystal clear: In the 1973rd item of the array (index 1972) the value for key `song_name` is a number. You have to add a custom initializer to fix the issue for example

```
struct Song: Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let title : String
    // ... other struct members

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "song_id"
        case title = "song_name"
    // ... other CodingKeys
    }        

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        do {
            self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        } catch {
            let numberName = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .title)
            self.title = String(numberName)
        }
        // other lines to initialize the other struct members
    }
}
```

If the error still persists the *number* could be also `Double` or `Bool`.

Comment: When we put the type as optional it still doesn't parse the JSON, ideally, it should parse with a nil value for the data that it was not able to parse.

Eg

struct Song: Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let title : String?
}

so when we decode it should have value in id but not in the title. 
but the error comes is unable to parse JSON. How to fix this without crashing the app